# Counterpart to PHP’s preg_match in Python

Tags: php, python, regex, preg-match

I am planning to move one of my scrapers to Python. I am comfortable using `preg_match` and `preg_match_all` in PHP. I am not finding a suitable function in Python similar to `preg_match`. Could anyone please help me in doing so?

For example, if I want to get the content between `<a class="title"` and `</a>`, I use the following function in PHP:

```
preg_match_all('/a class="title"(.*?)<\/a>/si',$input,$output);
```

Whereas in Python I am not able to figure out a similar function.

Comment: Here's the python regex docs: http://docs.python.org/howto/regex.html

Comment: In Python we don't use regular expressions for parsing HTML, we use [BeautifulSoup](http://www.crummy.com/software/BeautifulSoup/). See http://stackoverflow.com/a/1732454/78845

Answer (score 14, accepted):

You looking for python's [re module](http://docs.python.org/library/re.html).

Take a look at [re.findall](http://docs.python.org/library/re.html#re.findall) and [re.search](http://docs.python.org/library/re.html#re.search).

And as you have mentioned you are trying to parse html use `html parsers` for that. There are a couple of option available in python like [lxml](http://lxml.de/) or [BeautifulSoup](http://www.crummy.com/software/BeautifulSoup/).

Take a look at this [Why you should not parse html with regex](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1732348/regex-match-open-tags-except-xhtml-self-contained-tags/1732454#1732454)

Answer (score 5):

I think you need somthing like that:

```
output = re.search('a class="title"(.*?)<\/a>', input, flags=re.IGNORECASE)
    if output is not None:
        output = output.group(0)
        print(output)
```

you can add (?s) at the start of regex to enable multiline mode:

```
output = re.search('(?s)a class="title"(.*?)<\/a>', input, flags=re.IGNORECASE)
    if output is not None:
        output = output.group(0)
        print(output)
```

Answer (score 2):

You might be interested in reading about [Python Regular Expression Operations](http://docs.python.org/library/re.html)