# Making my password generator only allow certain symbols

Tags: python

```
incorrectPassword= True
while incorrectPassword:
    password = input("type in your password: ")
    if len(password) < 8:
        print("your password must be 8 characters long")
    if len(password) >24:
        print("Your password must be shorter than 24 characters")
    elif not any(i.isdigit() for i in password):
        print("you need a number in your password")
    elif not any(i.isupper() for i in password):
        print("you need a capital letter in your password")
    elif not any(i.islower() for i in password):
        print("you need a lowercase letter in your password")
        incorrectPassword = False
```

How can I only allow certain characters (like `!, $, %, ^, &, *, (, ), -, _, =` or `+`) as needed input?

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Counterpart to PHP’s preg\_match in Python](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/9061844/counterpart-to-php-s-preg-match-in-python)

Comment: Thou shalt not limit the number of characters in passwords nor limit the symbols allowed.

Comment: don't do this. look up the nist recommendations.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I would use regex, but to do it in a similar fashion to your other tests:

```
any(i not in '!$%^&*()-_=+' for i in password)
```

Answer (score 0):

you can simply use

```
elif " " in password:
    #print error
```

or use Python's [re](https://docs.python.org/2/library/re.html) package to define what characters are allowed in your password